# Selenium: How to intercept request

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Some body know how to intercept/get request url (XHR) and response in Selenium WebDriver? Is it possible?

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308067/get-xhr-response-network-traffic-and-parse-it-in-katalon-studio.

Answer (score 4):

Its not directly supported by webdriver, but you can capture all traffic by redirecting it through a proxy. In java..

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
// This should be the address of proxy.
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8080");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```