# JavaScript Selenium: How to intercept/stub request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, jestjs

I have been working with selenium + jest for testing my react application for a while and I'm trying to figure out how to intercept all requests (XMLHttpRequest) to avoid making actual network requests in my test cases.

After looking around, trying out a couple of third party libraries without any luck, I eventually switched over to using Google's Puppeteer instead of Selenium, since they have included interception inside the lib. But it only support chrome testing, so a year later I'm back at Selenium.

**My question is**: is there any ways of intercepting requests with Selenium javascript tests? I feel like I have missed something fundamental here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: How to intercept request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391104/selenium-how-to-intercept-request)

Comment: @MateMrše Yes. It's from 2012 though, so I was wondering if there's anything new on it.

Comment: it's 2024 now, are there any news?