# Get XHR response (network traffic) and parse it in Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, xmlhttprequest, automated-tests, katalon-studio, network-traffic

How can I read an XHR response and parse it in Katalon Studio?

I currently use a workaround way of testing responsiveness of my app: I use various `waitForElement_*_()` (*=visible, clickable, present, not-visible, not-clickable, not-present) commands in order to measure loading time of various elements.

I would like to get more specific and measure the duration of network requests (that can be seen in DevTools - network traffic).

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Katalon 7 and with and with [Chrome DevTools Protocol Integration plugin](https://store.katalon.com/product/144/Chrome-DevTools-Protocol-Integration), as was described [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/intercepting-request-with-chrome-devtools-protocol) you can intercept network requests.

The following example shows how to mock search requests in Wikipedia so that the result will always be “Katalon Studio”.

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.github.kklisura.cdt.protocol.commands.Fetch as Fetch
import com.github.kklisura.cdt.protocol.commands.Page as Page
import com.github.kklisura.cdt.services.ChromeDevToolsService as ChromeDevToolsService
import com.katalon.cdp.CdpUtils as CdpUtils
import com.kms.katalon.core.util.internal.Base64 as Base64
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject

WebUI.openBrowser('')
ChromeDevToolsService cdts = CdpUtils.getService()
Page page = cdts.getPage()
Fetch fetch = cdts.getFetch()
fetch.onRequestPaused({ def requestIntercepted ->
    String interceptionId = requestIntercepted.getRequestId()
    String url = requestIntercepted.getRequest().getUrl()
    boolean isMocked = url.contains('api.php')
    String response = '["Katalon Studio",["Katalon Studio"],["Katalon Studio is an automation testing solution developed by Katalon LLC."],["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katalon_Studio"]]'
    String rawResponse = Base64.encode(response)
    System.out.printf('%s - %s%s', isMocked ? 'MOCKED' : 'CONTINUE', url, System.lineSeparator())
    if (isMocked) {
        fetch.fulfillRequest(interceptionId, 200, new ArrayList(), rawResponse, null)
    } else {
        fetch.continueRequest(interceptionId)
    }
})

fetch.enable()
page.enable()
WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
TestObject searchInput = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, '#searchInput')
TestObject containing = new TestObject().addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, "//div[div[contains(.,'containing...')]]")
WebUI.setText(searchInput, 'Intercept request')
WebUI.waitForElementVisible(containing, 10)
```

**NOTES:**

Original post on Katalon forum: https://forum.katalon.com/t/intercepting-request-with-chrome-devtools-protocol/36081.

Sample project used in this topic: https://github.com/katalon-studio-samples/katalon-studio-chrome-devtools-protocol-plugin-samples.

The plugin uses https://github.com/kklisura/chrome-devtools-java-client to connect to CDP.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it can be done using Katalon studio. I am replying to your post, because I use network traffic information to derive performance numbers, and I use browsermobproxy.

Needless to say, this reply does not answer your question, just an option of using browsermobproxy

[How to access the values of Chrome's Dev tools Network tab's Request or summary using Selenium in python/java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46936851/how-to-access-the-values-of-chromes-dev-tools-network-tabs-request-or-summary/46939621#46939621)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I need to have browsermobproxy disabled in the Katalon Studio v 5.10.1.