# Katalon - Verifying form data by checking the network request

Tags: api, groovy, katalon-studio

I am using a Katalon tool + groovy scripts for UI automation.

The page I would like to test has a number of filter fields of a different types (text fields, date pickers, etc.) and submit button that sends the request to the server.

I wasn't able to find any relevant information for the following issue:
is it possible to get the request that was sent by the browser to the server in order to parse and verify the parameters values?

Thanks in advance,
IM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to distinguish between UI and API Testing. For UI-Test you have to check the behaviour of UI and the correctness of all elements that are displayed.
With API Testing you can verify that your request are receiving correct status codes and responses for different sent form data.
For API Testing see https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/introduction_api_testing.html#what-is-api-testing

Comment: I agree those are different types of testing. However, I'm also interested in combining the two: intercepting the request sent by clicking an UI element. That's what I was trying to get to [by asking this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308067/get-xhr-response-network-traffic-and-parse-it-in-katalon-studio).

Comment: I agree with you, that it would be nice to have this option. But to my knowledge it is not possible at this moment to realize it with Katalon.